# Link created by eRuby have the same? number every time I refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The link created by [eRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby#erb) have the same? number every time I refresh.

Such as

```
<img alt="Auto" class="list-image" src="/images/auto.jpg?1287492558" />
```

the ?1287492558

And with it I can't load the thing with question marks and numbers. And I can load it as soon as I delete the thing. So as the style sheet that I load dynamically using eRuby.

I also discovered that

- I would able to load the image for
  the first time, the 3rd time, the 6th time
  and so on.
- And load my stylesheet for the first
  time only. Not after refresh.
- the ?number is always the same every time I refresh
- when I request the link of an image using different ?number, it can be loaded. But with the same ?number "Internal Server Error private method `gsub!' called for #" shows.

So, what is the purpose of ?1287492558 and how to delete it or how to make Ruby on Rails load the image URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with using [Mongrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongrel_%28web_server%29). Don't use [WEBrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick).

Answer (score 1):

don't know how to delete it, but the purpose of it is to avoid the browser from caching this image. It's a trick used forever - adding a timestamp to a resource to make it look like a new resource, and thus not use the cached version.

Comment: But the rails server seem not to generate a new resource ... what might be the possible reason?  I am using ubuntu with Rails 2.2.3

Comment: how do you know it's not generating a new resource? This request would be fulfilled by the static content server, not the dynamic rails (unless you mapped /images to go through the rails processor)

Comment: because the ?1287492558 is always the same every time i refresh. That is what i mean by resources. Sorry to confuse you. And thanks for helping me out

Comment: weird. this might be an artifact of some startup process. I am not an expert on rails - maybe Jacob Relkin (below) can help

Comment: because if the purpose of prevent caching , then the ?number should be different every time , but i have found out it is the same every time i load . So i think the problem is the same number every time?

Answer (score 1):

Opposite to what Anatoly and Jacob said, this number is used so that the browser WILL cache the static content. The number you see is the timestamp of last update on that file. So the number will remain the same, and your browser can cache that content, until the content is changed, so the last update time changes, and this causes all browsers to refresh the file in their caches. I don't know how to disable it, will check the docs and report back if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks , but from what i see from the documentation   stylesheet_link_tag "style" # =>
    <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
seems that no ?number will be generated

Comment: maybe i am in development state ?

Comment: probably. because in dev mode, no caching is active by default